# Как заставить Newtonsoft.Json вернуть чистый json?

Tags: c#, json

Есть сервис на сишарпе, который отдает js-скрипту json строку. Использую библиотеку Newtonsoft.Json. Но в моей реализации сервис оборачивает json в тег <string></string>, что, соответственно, мне мешает нормально работать с ним на клиенте. Как можно от него избавиться?

JS-код:

```
function VerifySignature() {
            var keyInfo = GetKeyInfo();
            // отправляем данные в контроллер для валидации сертификата
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "VerifySignatureService.asmx/VerifySignature",
                data: { certInfo: JSON.stringify(keyInfo) },
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(result);
                    console.log(result);
                }
            });
        }
```

C#-код:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class VerifySignatureService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public string VerifySignature(string certInfo)
        {
            ResponseType response = new ResponseType();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(certInfo) || certInfo == "[]")
            {
                response.isError = true;
                response.isValid = false;
                response.message = "Пришел пустой keyInfo";
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response);
            }
            var keyInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<KeyInfo>(certInfo);
            if (CertificateVerifier.VerifyCertificateSign(true, keyInfo))
            {
                response.isError = false;
                response.isValid = true;
                response.message = Resources.SuccessfullySigned;
            }
            else
            {
                response.isError = false;
                response.isValid = false;
                response.message = "Ваш ключ не прошел проверку";
            }
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response, Formatting.Indented);
        }
    }

    public class ResponseType
    {
        public string message;
        public bool isError;
        public bool isValid;
    }
```

Вывод console.log(result):

```
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">{ "message": "Документ успешно подписан", "isError": false, "isValid": true }</string>
```

Comment: Чё-то не то. А вы проверяли, что именно возвращает метод `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`? Не верится, что он добавляет левые теги.

Comment: @VladD, выдает 
{
  "message": "Документ успешно подписан",
  "isError": false,
  "isValid": true
}
то есть не оборачивет в тег. Думаю, это уже делает ajax-метод, но проблема в том, что если указать ему contentType="application/json" будет 500 ошибка

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать не "public string", а "public object", у меня такой проблемы не наблюдалось. Я также использовал $.getJSON, однако если JSON не валидный, как в вашем случае, то "success" не вызовется.

В своём проекте я делал так:

View:

```
     function getData()
     {
         $.getJSON("/Instruments/GetCandlesticksJson", { secname: cursec + timeInterval, limit: 50 })
                .done(function (jsondata) {
                    createChart(jsondata);
                });
     }
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public object GetCandlesticksJson(string secname, int limit)
{
    if (CurrentUser != null && (!CurrentUser.InRole("Guest") || !CurrentUser.InRole("User")))
        return Repository.GetCandlesticksJson(secname, limit);
    else
    return null;
}
```

Функция:

```
public IEnumerable<Candlestick> GetCandlesticks(string secname, int limit)
{
    if (_col == null)
        if (DbCandles.CollectionExists(secname))
            _col = DbCandles.GetCollection(secname);
        else
        {
            DbCandles.CreateCollection(secname);
            _col = DbCandles.GetCollection(secname);
        }
    int offset = (int)_col.Count() - limit;
    return _col.AsQueryable<Candlestick>()
        .Skip(offset >= 0 ? offset : 0)
        .Take(limit);
}

public object GetCandlesticksJson(string secname, int limit)
{
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(GetCandlesticks(secname, limit));
}
```